# Change UIViewController on button click without reloading content if content already loaded first time

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I am creating one ipad application where i have four button on above. i have to load different `UIViewController` (`oneViewController`,`twoViewController`,`ThreeViewController`..) on each button click inside `UIView` Control. All these Controller will show RSS feed coming from the website. now my problem is each time when i click button all data is loading from first. i just want to know is there any way to load data first time and just change the `UIViewController` without loading data from Rss again and again. i have below code to change the `UIViewController` on button click.

`- (IBAction)clickbtnComment:(id)sender {

   oneViewController *aViewController = [[oneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"oneViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.NewsScrollView addSubview:aViewController.view];
}`

Comment: For this one store one variable in NSUserDefaults and check weather coming first time or not if first time then load that page otherwise skip that one.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new view controller every time you click the button. If you stored the newly created view controller in a property the first time and just showed it if the view controller already exists, you wouldn't need to load the feeds again.